# Teaching determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, education

I am writing a first handout on determinants. The intended audience is confident with basic matrix algebra and the basic definitions of vector space theory. I just wondered if someone would comment on my layout and let me know whether they thought it appropriate. Thanks in advance.

$\underline{\text{Handout I}}$

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space.

*Definition.* Multilinear map.

*Definition.* Volume form on $V$ i.e. an alternating n-linear map $V^n\to F$.

**Proposition.** Volume forms are skew-symmetric.

*Remark.* Converse true unless $\operatorname{char}F = 2$.

**Proposition.** Let $f$ be a non-zero volume form on $V$. Then
$$f(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\neq 0 \Leftrightarrow v_1,\ldots,v_n \text{ is a basis for } V.$$

*Definition.* Define $\det:\operatorname{Mat}_n(F)\to F$ by
$$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1),1}\ldots a_{\sigma(n),n}.$$

*Note.* We can consider a matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(F)$ to be an $n$-tuple of column vectors.

$\hphantom{Note}$ In doing so, we obtain an isomorphism $\operatorname{Mat}_n(F)\cong F^n\oplus\ldots\oplus F^n$.

**Proposition.** $\det$ is a volume form on $F^n$.

**Theorem.** Let $f$ be any volume form on $F^n$. Then 
$$f=f(e_1,\ldots,e_n)\cdot\det.$$
In particular, $\det$ is the unique volume form on $F^n$ whose value at $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is $1$.

Comment: Consider asking at [matheducators.se] instead, which is a site  specifically about teaching mathematics.

Comment: Is your audience familiar with the symmetric group and the signum?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, they have had a first course in group theory which included the basic properties of the symmetric group.